# Get current date in javascript, format: day, date month

Tags: javascript

How can I get the date in javascript format: day, date month
example: Friday, 12 March

This gives me 12/3

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>    
    var d = new Date();
     
    var date = d.getUTCDate();
    var month = d.getUTCMonth() + 1; // Since getUTCMonth() returns month from 0-11 not 1-12

     
    var dateStr = date + "/" + month;
    document.write(dateStr);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [This is what you need.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Either use a locale specific format, i.e.  `(new Date()).toLocaleDateString('en-US', { weekday:'long', day: 'numeric', month:'long', })` which gives you '`Friday, March 12'` or build your custom format by formatting each individual field as you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses locale date's formate.

```js
const date = new Date();
var options = {
  weekday: 'long',
  month: 'long',
  day: 'numeric'
};

console.log(date.toLocaleDateString("default", options));
```

Or use  `date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options)`

Comment: Op wants "Friday, 12 March"

Answer (score 0):

try {date|date:"dd/MM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss"}